# Uploading the email sketch on ESP8266 via Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, blynk

I am working on a project to send an email when a button is pressed using arduino uno, wifi module ESP8266, and the Blynk App. I was able to upload the sketch on the wifi module (ESP8266), but it's not responding. Here is the output that I am getting from the serial monitor:

```
len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chks
```

I have looked online and I can't find a solution to this. Can anyone one please help?

Below is the sketch that I am uploading.
Thanks in advance!

```
#include <Blynk.h>

/* Comment this out to disable prints and save space */
#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial
/* Set this to a bigger number, to enable sending longer messages */
#define BLYNK_MAX_SENDBYTES 128

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h>

// You should get Auth Token in the Blynk App.
// Go to the Project Settings (nut icon).
char auth[] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

// Your WiFi credentials.
// Set password to "" for open networks.
char ssid[] = "XXXXXXX";
char pass[] = "";

void emailOnButtonPress()
{
  // *** WARNING: You are limited to send ONLY ONE E-MAIL PER 15 SECONDS! ***

  // Let's send an e-mail when you press the button
  // connected to digital pin 2 on your Arduino

  int isButtonPressed = !digitalRead(2); // Invert state, since button is "Active LOW"

  if (isButtonPressed) // You can write any condition to trigger e-mail sending
  {
    Serial.println("Button is pressed."); // This can be seen in the Serial Monitor
    Blynk.email("xxxxxxx@gmail.com", "Subject: Button Logger", "You just pushed the button...");

    // Or, if you want to use the email specified in the App (like for App Export):
    //Blynk.email("Subject: Button Logger", "You just pushed the button...");
  }
}

void setup()
{
  // Debug console
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass);
  // You can also specify server:
  //Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass, "blynk-cloud.com", 8442);
  //Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass, IPAddress(192,168,1,100), 8442);

  // Send e-mail when your hardware gets connected to Blynk Server
  // Just put the recepient's "e-mail address", "Subject" and the "message body"
  Blynk.email("xxxxxx@gmail.com", "Subject", "My Blynk project is online.");

  // Setting the button
  pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  // Attach pin 2 interrupt to our handler
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), emailOnButtonPress, CHANGE);
}

void loop()
{
  Blynk.run();
}
```

Comment: the button is attached to Uno? you read the pin 2 of esp8266. what is attached there?

Comment: The button is connected to the arduino uno. I got this code from the Blynk website.

Comment: the Blynk example is for esp8266 and the button should be connected to esp8266, because digitalRead in esp reads the pins of esp. no Uno needed